# Hide menu before login and show after

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, layout, view

Hi guys I have a bit of a problem here, I was setting my login page to be the start up page for my site I managed to get that done by using [Authorize] in HomeController but now the menu bar is showing. I don't want it to show before the user logs in I want the menu to appear after logging in.anyone who can help me please.

here is my menu below(Code from view main Layout)

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font:bold;">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vehicles", "Vehicles", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("VehicleTrips", "VehicleTrips", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Report", "Index", "Report")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("OffVehicles", "OffVehicles", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("MovingState", "MovingState", "Home")</li>

    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
  </div>
```

Comment: don't use lay out for login page

Comment: What's the problem with your current code? It's exactly the way to go: a `if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` code block to conditionally display the menu.

Comment: @Imad I didnt't use it but the menu shows on my login page and i dont want it to be showing. the code above is the menu i wanna hide from my login page

Comment: @ken2k the code if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) is working it hides the links not the whole bar living a bar on top. i don't know whether its possible to hide even the bar?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Are you just wanting to hide something in your layout? If so, you can wrap it with the same `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` conditional there in your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing `_Layout` in your Login page because `_ViewStart.cshtml` file sets it behind the scene. This file is present under `Views/Shared` folder. You can disable `_Layout` for specific view by setting by setting `Layout` property to null.

So set

```
@{
    Layout =  null;
}
```

at the top of your view.

Comment: Thank you so much @Imad your code is working :) I now do not see the menu bar when i land in the login page.

Comment: I don't know if I'd actually recommend this approach. It will "work", but only because you're just brute forcing the removal of everything but the view contents. In other words, you're actually send a malformed HTML document with no `html`, `head`, or `body` tags. The user's browser will compensate, but you might run into other weird issues.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks man for your input the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated worked and my code is working now just as i wanted it to.